# import PyOpenPose as OP ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found

Tags: python-3.x, dll, module, openpose

Working on a Windows 10

Trying to set up pose2pose, which needs PyOpenPose and OpenPose to run
keep running into the issue in the code below:

I'v added every combination of every variable to my paths, and my PYTHONPATH and even made python37.pth and directed it to my module and still nothing.

Edit: when building PyOpenPose built with Cmake and then in visual studio 2019, the config propertys were set to .dll but no .dll was made, instead i have a .lib, .exe, and .pyd in C:\Users\conta\Documents\GithubRepos\pyopenpose\build\PyOpenPoseLib\Release

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_train_data.py", line 5, in <module>
    import PyOpenPose as OP
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
```

Comment: some links to where i'm coming from if it's helpful:
https://github.com/FORTH-ModelBasedTracker/PyOpenPose
https://github.com/GordonRen/pose2pose
https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose